# Meteor adding html elements from collection

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have data that needs to be displayed in collection. I should iterate through collection and create html element based on each element in collection.

I want to insert Cards which look like this in html code.

```
    <div class="card #66bb6a green lighten-1">
       <div class="card-content white-text">
          <span class="card-title">{{ title }}</span>
          {{#if currentUser}}
             <p>{{ currentUser }}</p>
          {{/if}}
       </div>
       <div class="card-action">
          <a class="card-nav" href="#">Navigation</a>
          <a class="card-remove" href="#">Remove</a>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Notice that click event should be on both a elements (card-nav, card-remove). 
What is the best way to do this? Can this be created with one template and then inserting each template based on collection?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: if you want to create multiple templates just wrap them in an if statement,if you dont want to change the structure of your card then just change classes.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. Each template should look like this with different properties (title etc.). I don't have problem with setting them. I don't know how to add them in javascript code and set them events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add helpers example:

```
Template.your_template_name.helpers({ //getting the data from collection and assign it to a helper
  yourdata: function() {
    return some_collection.find({});
  }
});
```

and in your blaze just add it like that

```
<div class="card #66bb6a green lighten-1">
   <div class="card-content white-text">
      <span class="card-title">{{ yourdata.title }}</span> //asign youdata.title 
        {{#if currentUser}}
           <p>{{ currentUser }}</p>
        {{/if}}
   </div>
   <div class="card-action">
     <a class="card-nav" href="#">Navigation</a>
       <a class="card-remove" href="#">Remove</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

in order to to remove or navigate you add events

```
Template.your_template_name.events({
    "click .card-remove": function () {         
      some_collection.remove(this._id);
    }
 })
```

you could do that with each
in your main template add

```
{{#each yourdata}}
    {{> your_template_name}}
{{/each}}


<template name="your_template_name">
  <div class="card #66bb6a green lighten-1">
       <div class="card-content white-text">
          <span class="card-title">{{ title }}</span>
          {{#if currentUser}}
             <p>{{ currentUser }}</p>
          {{/if}}
       </div>
       <div class="card-action">
          <a class="card-nav" href="#">Navigation</a>
          <a class="card-remove" href="#">Remove</a>
       </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

i would suggest to look over at meteor.com they have some good tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but you didn't understand me. I know how to add data to templates and register events and helpers. The problem is I need to insert multiple templates (same structure). Not only one. Therefore, looping through collection and inserting template for each one. 

Example: 
if my collection has 10 elements, I need to create 10 templates.
I've tried this and it only creates 1 template.

Comment: @Wolf add {{each}} in your template see updated answer i added an example.

Comment: Thanks a ton man. This works like a charm. I didn't know the true power of each in Meteor :D